# Django Error : django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, django-1.10

I'm not quite sure what is going wrong here, I have added all the apps in settings.py file, successfully ran the migrations with manage.py etc. but i keep getting this error.
I'm running this in PyCharm 2017.2.2 and I don't see any errors in my scripts either. All the required packages seems to be installed.

Below is the stack trace :

```
__import__(module)
from models import Token, Narrative

self = load(from_parent)
      File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
__import__(module)
        return Unpickler(file).load()
      File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>
from models import Token, Narrative
class Narrative(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
      File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    from models import Token, Narrative
            dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
class Narrative(models.Model):
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
        klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
class Narrative(models.Model):
self.check_apps_ready()
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
__import__(module)
              File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
__import__(module)
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
        django.core.exceptions  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
self.check_apps_ready()
from models import Token, Narrative
.          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
AppRegistryNotReadyfrom models import Token, Narrative
self.check_apps_ready()
        :   File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
class Narrative(models.Model):
A        django.core.exceptions  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
pps aren't loaded yet.class Narrative(models.Model):
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
.
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
django.core.exceptionsAppRegistryNotReadyapp_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
    .:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
AppRegistryNotReadyA  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    : pps aren't loaded yet.    self.check_apps_ready()
A
self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
pps aren't loaded yet.  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready

Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
django.core.exceptions.  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    .AppRegistryNotReadyAppRegistryNotReadyself = load(from_parent)
    : :   File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
self = load(from_parent)
AA      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
pps aren't loaded yet.    pps aren't loaded yet.return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
[26/Aug/2017 13:02:01] "GET /getStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 3


  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
    self = load(from_parent)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
self = load(from_parent)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
dispatch[key](self)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
return Unpickler(file).load()
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
return Unpickler(file).load()
              File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
dispatch[key](self)
__import__(module)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>
dispatch[key](self)
              File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
__import__(module)
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
      File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>
from models import Token, Narrative
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
from models import Token, Narrative
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
class Narrative(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
        __import__(module)
        class Narrative(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>
__import__(module)
self = load(from_parent)
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
      File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    from models import Token, Narrative
        app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
from models import Token, Narrative
self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
      File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    class Narrative(models.Model):
        self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
class Narrative(models.Model):
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
django.core.exceptions    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
    .return Unpickler(file).load()
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
AppRegistryNotReadyapp_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
django.core.exceptions:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    .A    self.check_apps_ready()
AppRegistryNotReadypps aren't loaded yet.self.check_apps_ready()

:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
A        pps aren't loaded yet.dispatch[key](self)
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
django.core.exceptions        .raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
AppRegistryNotReadydjango.core.exceptions  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
: .    AAppRegistryNotReady__import__(module)
pps aren't loaded yet.:   File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\tokenization.py", line 34, in <module>

A    pps aren't loaded yet.from models import Token, Narrative

  File "C:\Users\moham\Downloads\GQP Project\final\app1\models.py", line 27, in <module>
    class Narrative(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
self = load(from_parent)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
          File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
```